# Issue with json_rpc over https

Tags: javascript, rpc, json-rpc

Hello my site is powered by https. The config.js file is located in the root folder of the site, it specifies which address to access via the API. The address is specified https://127.0.0.1:10000/json_rpc, requests to this address do not work. If you specify http://127.0.0.1:10000/json_rpc, then everything works. How can I call the API over https and not over http? Or is there a workaround in the config.js itself?

If you make a request via curl https://127.0.0.1:10000/json_rpc, then curl error appears: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:10000

Comment: Your browser is blocking localhost as unsecure. This is a complicated problem. The best solution is to create a CA cert authority, to be installed in every browser, sign your server keys, and you will get a grey lock. Then your query will works.

Comment: A patchy solution can be visiting https://127.0.0.1:10000 and accept the warning self signed ssl certificat, if the message appears

Comment: Or get a cheap domain name and use caddy server this will be automatic, but warning you will route your local ip to the internet.

Comment: I use the ip address of the Ubuntu 18.04 server, it is external. It has nginx and a certificate from letsencrypt. But https request command doesn't work.